# Seeking Saudi Arabia County borders as KML?

Tags: geospatial, kml

Anyone knows where I can find Saudi Arabia County border as KML file?

I searched the net with no success

Comment: Related to this broad question: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/10826/6229

Comment: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=7a8585998b7f470b85235dcdb560c7e2 and I think openstreetmap.org should have these as well.

Answer (score 1):

Polygeo's comment's link highlights some issues you may have. But as for a simple outline of Saudi Arabia GADM or DIVA-GIS will both be good sources. They won't be in KML (I believe their data come in .shp form) but you can easily convert to KML using a multitude of free tool.